# AS3 - Error #1009 - But it's debug is referencing a function?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've found lots of questions and answers about this error, but I'm having trouble because my error seems to referencing the function name and not any instance name on my timeline.

**Error**

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at mpu_fla::MainTimeline/playAnimation()
```

**My Code**

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playAnimation);
function playAnimation(e:MouseEvent):void
{ 
animation_logosout.play(); 
} 

stop();
```

I'm not quite sure it's telling me it can't find the function name? Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm new to AS3!

Thanks!

Comment: do me a favor, put a `trace("!!!");` right above `animation_logosout.play()`, test the movie and tell us what happens. I suspect that either animation_logosout or myButton doesn't exist.

Comment: Here is the debug output:

    !!!
    TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a     null object reference.
 at mpu_fla::MainTimeline/playAnimation()

Comment: So, this should tell you that the `playAnimation`function has been found, because you get the correct "!!!" trace in the console. But it breaks right after that, because animation_logosout does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

`animation_logosout` is undefined. Check if the object is present on stage on the same frame, and check if the instance name is set correctly.

Comment: I've double checked through all the instance names, and everything is correctly named. Does it matter that it sits in a different part of the timeline?

Comment: Yes it does. You can't refer to objects on other frames directly... because they're just not there.

Comment: I thought I could have a master layer with all my AS3 over the top?

Comment: I'm given this compile error now:

Scene 1, Layer 'Vector Smart Object', Frame 30, Line 2, Column 10 1021: Duplicate function definition.
Scene 1, Layer 'Vector Smart Object', Frame 30, Line 2, Column 10 1023: Incompatible override.

Comment: Yeah... you might want to show me some more code for that. It's related to other things you have in your fla, but those aren't on this webpage.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm going to go through the file and tidy it up.

Comment: It's working now, a problem with me just not knowing you have to place the Actionscript on the layer you want it to work with.

Comment: also if you are using keyframes in the timeline, make sure the movieclip you are referencing (animation_logosout) is named the same on every keyframe. It might even be better to dont use keyframes on the timeline where the MC animation_logosout lives